# Autorun USB in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, usb, autorun

How could I get an autorun USB drive in Windows 7/8/10. autorun.inf doesn't seem to work anymore. Also could this work without any rubber duckie USB drives? Maybe trick windows into thinking it is a DVD or CD to autorun?

Comment: If Settings > Devices > Autoplay > Use AutoPlay for all media devices is on, it should work, also for a usb drive. The default setting is, that it asks what you want to do.

Comment: I think that should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean AutoPlay, you can set it up like this:

1. Open Control Panel and navigate to 'Hardware And Sound' > 'AutoPlay'.
2. Find the 'Removable Drive' option.

[image: Screenshot of the option]

3. Change the dropdown to:

- 'Take no action' - disable AutoPlay completely
- 'Open folder to view files (File Explorer)' - Open the USB in file explorer when it is connected.
- 'Ask me every time' - Show a program chooser: most likely what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to change a windows registry entry to allow media to be run automatically so that the autorun.inf file can be executed once the device is plugged in

```
[autorun]
Icon=lock.ico
Label=Payroll Information
;Open=FetchSalariesDB.EXE
ShellExecute=FetchSalariesDB.EXE
UseAutoPlay=1
```

Comment: AutoPlay for EXE-files on removable rewritable drives doesn't work since Windows 7...

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is a way,

to do this you have to convert your USB into "NTFS" normally its "FAT32"
To do this, find your USB drive on your computer
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkFOK.png -- Image (just my USB drive)
Then right-click on that USB drive. Then click on "Change Format" or "Format" https://i.stack.imgur.com/42yLK.png -- Picture of that. Then click and change it to "NTFS" instead of "FAT32" https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziA67.png -- And another picture of that. Then all you have to do from here is making a regular autorun.inf file and it will autorun whatever you desire, and it even works without the permission from "**AutoPlay**" Have fun :)

Comment: Changing my drive's format to NTFS still does not get autorun.inf to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work, I changed my drives format to NTFS and it still didn't autorun.