# To execute a program from a USB drive

Tags: usb

"I have a regular USB memory stick. I want it so that when I plug it into the computer, it runs a .exe program. I noticed that with the rubber ducky, it only types commands. I also tried autorun but it doesn't work. What can I do?"

Resolving the probleme

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autorun USB in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46270274/autorun-usb-in-windows-10)   If this doesn't help, you'll need to elaborate on exactly what steps you did to enable Autorun and how you tested it.